# Free CVS reporting tools

Tags: reporting, cvs

Please suggest me good and free reporting tools which works with CVS in Windows environment? The purpose of the reporting is to get the most detailed information from a CVS repository, including committing activity on a per user basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [statCVS](http://statcvs.sourceforge.net/).

Here is a brief set of feature list from their site:

- Timeline for the lines of code
- Lines of code for each developer
- Activity by Clock time
- Authors Activity
- Author activity per Module
- Author Most Recent Commits with links to ViewVc
- Stats per directory
- File count
- Average file size
- Largest files
- Files with most revisions
- Directory Sizes
- Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
- Repository tree with file count and lines of code
- LOC and Churn the evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day
- Repo Map the dynamic hierarchical view of your repo for the last 30 days