# File churn in CVS

Tags: file, cvs

I'm looking to find the number of times that each file has changed on a particular branch in our cvs repository. I'm particularly looking for all the files which have changed the most. A "top 40" list would be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>This was added as an edit by the original asker, I have converted it to a community wiki answer because it should be an answer, not an edit.</sub>

In this case, the branch has been in use for about 6 months. If I set to the latest in that branch ("cvs -z9 co -r r80m-1 ..."), it looks like the last number of the revision is the number of changes in the current branch -- if the file has been changed in the past 180 days, then it's on this branch. I'm using linux, so I eventually did it this way:

```
for file in `find . \! \( -name CVS -prune \) -type f -mtime -180`
do
   cvs status "$file" | grep Working.revision | gawk -v FNAME=$file '{ print FNAME gensub(/(\.)([0-9]*)$/, "\\1\\2 churn:\\2  ", 1) }' >> cvs_churn.txt
done
sort -k3 -t: -n cvs_churn.txt | uniq
```

So, for each line in "cvs status" output like:

```
Working revision: 1.2.34
```

The gawk command changes it to:

```
./path/file.c Working revision: 1.2.34        churn:34
```

and I can then sort on ":34".

---

This works, but it's pretty crude. I'm hoping others may be able to answer with better approaches.

I've seen in some other questions eg: [Free CVS reporting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804941) people have mentioned statCVS. It sounds interesting (more than I need, but some of the other info might also be useful). However, it says it only works on the "default" branch. The documentation was a little unclear -- can I set to the branch of interest, and use it for this?